# echo a shortcode in a shortcode code?

Tags: shortcode

I have a code for shortcode like this

[mt_ptcolumn size="pricing-3-col" title="Bronze" price="$99" period="1 domain" button="Purchase" url="#"]

and I want to add a shortcode inside button="" like this

[mt_ptcolumn size="pricing-3-col" title="Bronze" price="$99" period="1 domain" **button="[another-shortcode]"** url="#"]

but it doesnt work. So how do I edit the code below to make it works?

```
if (!function_exists('mt_ptcolumn')) {
    function mt_ptcolumn($atts, $content = null) {
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'title'     => 'Basic',
            'price'     => '$40',
            'period'    => 'per month',
            'url'       => '#',
            'button'    => 'Buy Now!'
        ), $atts));

        $ptoutput ='';
        $ptoutput .= '<div class="pt-column">'."\n";
        $ptoutput .= '<h3>'.$title.'</h3>'."\n";
        $ptoutput .= '<div id="tab_price" class="pt-cost"><p>'.$price.'<span>'.$period.'</span></p></div>'."\n";
        $ptoutput .= '<div id="tab_btn" class="pt-cost"><a href="'.$url.'" class="mt-button large" style="margin-top:25px">'.$button.'</a></div>'."\n";
        $ptoutput .= '<div class="pt-features">'."\n";
        $ptoutput .= do_shortcode($content);
        $ptoutput .= '</div>'."\n";
        $ptoutput .= '<div class="pt-buynow"><a href="'.$url.'" class="mt-button large">'.$button.'</a></div>'."\n";
        $ptoutput .= '</div>'."\n";

        return $ptoutput;
    }
    add_shortcode('mt_ptcolumn', 'mt_ptcolumn');
}
```

Thank you

Comment: This question has been asked and answered numerous times. [Please search the site before asking a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=nested+shortcode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to execute `do_shortcode()` on your `$button`.

```
$ptoutput .= '<div class="pt-buynow"><a href="' . $url . '" class="mt-button large">' . do_shrtcode( $button ) . '</a></div>' . "\n";
```

**Be aware of endless recursions!**

You may also check if the `$button` is set as a shortcode, if you want to force one.

```
if ( !has_shortcode( $button, 'another_shortcode' ) ) { // Fallbacks to enforce the Shortcode
```

As this is not tested, you may have to add the brackets of your shortcode in `$button` afterwards, to ensure the original shortcode does work properly, but unfortunately I do not know exactly if you need to do that.

```
$button = '[' . $button . ']';
```